# Dynamically populate a select field’s choices from a select field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a select field that have 4 values.

```
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
Value 4
```

When the User selects one of these, I want to load the sub select field of that parent, so if I choose Value 1 I want a different select field too show up and to be chosen from.

```
Subvalue 1
Subvalue 2
```

**How can I create a subselect field and how to add values and connect it to the first selection?**

I read some about dynamically loading, but I'm not sure how to do it.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/

Comment: That's not really what you're looking for. You'll need to write some JavaScript. Create the sub select field, hide it with JavaScript when the page loads, and make it show if your first select field matches your requirements.

Comment: Yes but it has to be done in the Post create. I am trying to choose a country and it's city, so first I choose a country and then I get to select a city , in the post creation in admin panel. Do you understand?